# preg_match_all returns only every second match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have program like this:

```
$txt = "
{ABC}
+ 1
- 1

{DEF}
+ 2
- 2

{IJK}
+ 3
- 3

{LMN}
+ 4 
- 4
";
preg_match_all('/\{.*?\{/s', $txt, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

and I want to match everything between two opening curly brackets (or end of of text).
But my result contains only the ABC and IJK block, since the next { is already eaten up.

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(16) "{ABC}
+ 1
- 1

{"
    [1]=>
    string(16) "{IJK}
+ 3
- 3

{"
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that with your actual string, a simple `explode("\n\n", $txt)` (or `preg_split('~\R\R~', $txt)` if you are not sure of the newline sequence) gives you the correct result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the regex [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?=)` operator will allow you to match whatever comes before a `{` without actually matching the `{` character itself.

```
preg_match_all('/\{.*?(?=\{)/s', $txt, $matches)
```

Will give you this result:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(15) "{ABC}
+ 1
- 1

"
    [1]=>
    string(15) "{DEF}
+ 2
- 2

"
    [2]=>
    string(15) "{IJK}
+ 3
- 3

"
  }
}
```

You mentioned you also wanted to match what comes between a `{` and the end of the text. You can do that by using the [pipe](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `|` operator and the end of string [anchor](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `$` inside the lookahead.

```
preg_match_all('/\{.*?(?=\{|$)/s', $txt, $matches)
```

Will give you the result you want:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(15) "{ABC}
+ 1
- 1

"
    [1]=>
    string(15) "{DEF}
+ 2
- 2

"
    [2]=>
    string(15) "{IJK}
+ 3
- 3

"
    [3]=>
    string(14) "{LMN}
+ 4 
- 4"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^` which will match any char except an opening parenthesis.

That way it would match from an opening `{` till either the next occurrence of `{` or the end of string.

```
{[^{]*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lXFmQj/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/YcITh)

For example

```
preg_match_all('/{[^{]*/', $txt, $matches);
```